# Term describing array vs matrix operations in R

Tags: arrays, r, terminology

Matlab has the notion of scalar vs [vector/array vs matrix operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)  relating in part to whether or not the operation is element-wise. R has the additional behavior of recycling peculiar to it, but I'm wondering by what term the R community refers to array operations. I'd like to use the official term if any in some documentation of some classes that attempt to mirror R operations in C++ in our codebase.